# Seeking a particular book on Science vs. Halacha

Tags: product-recommendation, science, books-generally

About 15 years ago, I recall that there was a book put out by the Association of Orthodox Jewish Scientists. It was titled something like "Challenge - Science against Halacha" or something similar. I remember that it had a yellow sleeve cover.

Does anyone know the name of that book and where I may be able to purchase this?

Comment: If you are interested in other books on the topic you might want to look at books by [Gerald Schroeder](http://www.amazon.com/Gerald-L.-Schroeder/e/B000APV1XA) or [The challenge of creation](http://www.amazon.com/Challenge-Creation-Encounter-Cosmology-Evolution/dp/9652295949/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1451578190&sr=1-2&refinements=p_27%3ANatan+Slifkin) by R Natan Slifkin

Comment: The accepted answer below is the first (and only) result when searching with keyword `association of orthodox jewish scientists` and title word `challenge` at http://www.worldcat.org/advancedsearch. It is also the first result when searching for `challenge science halacha` at http://books.google.com/. It is also on the first page of results when searching for `challenge science halacha` at http://www.amazon.com/books. −1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably looking for [*Challenge: Torah Views on Science and Its Problems*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0873061748), edited by [R' Aryeh Carmell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryeh_Carmell) and [Dr. Cyril Domb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyril_Domb) in association with the [Association of Orthodox Jewish Scientists](http://www.aojs.org/), published by [Feldheim](http://www.feldheim.com/) in 1976 (1st edition) and 1988 (2nd edition).

Comment: Good find. I believe that's the one. Thanks!

Comment: @DanF This was on the shelf in my college's Hillel, and I used to pull it down and read essays in it from time to time.

Comment: Very interesting book. Which college hillel? Who was Hillel director then?

Comment: @DanF MIT. The library in the Hillel Center there probably predated the Hillel director at the time.

Comment: Great college. Being a MIT student would explain your liking this book :-)